# C# WPF always align controls relative to window background image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application where I use a background image.

```
 <Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/background.png"/>
</Window.Background>
```

In the window I have grids and columns definitions.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Everytime the window size is changed, the background image is resized, which is okay. 
The problem is that the controls in the form are loosing their position. 
The background looks this way: 
[image: Background image]

I need to add textboxes in between the lines so it can look like this: 
[image: Desired solution]

So far I tried canvas, dockpanel, putting the textboxes in different user control, but nothing helped.
The controls do not have margins/width or height only rowspan and columnspan.

Any idea would be helpful :) thanks!

Comment: Instead of Window.Background, use an Image element as first child of the Grid and set its RowSpan and ColumnSpan properties so that it covers all cells.

Answer (score 1):

Your Textboxes need to be sized relative to the window size. You can define the colum widths and line heights as fractions of the width and height by specifying a size with a star (*).
See example below for a starting point. You can of course tweak the numbers a bit.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.29*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.02*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.29*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.55*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>
</Grid>
```